# Hovering and playing video

Tags: hover, html5-video, aurelia, jquery-hover

I'm trying to make a gallery of videos that play on hover...and only when hovered. But for some reason, sometimes the videos continue to play even when the mouse exits them.

I'm using aurelia's `mouseover.delegate="hoverVideo($index)"`and `mouseout.delegate="hideVideo($index)"` to initiate the playback.

```
  hoverVideo = index => {
    let id = "#video" + "-" + index.toString();

    let isPlaying =
      $(id).get(0).currentTime > 0 &&
      !$(id).get(0).paused &&
      !$(id).get(0).ended &&
      $(id).get(0).readyState > 2;

    if (!isPlaying) {
      $(id)
        .get(0)
        .play();
    }
  };
  hideVideo = index => {
    let id = "#video" + "-" + index.toString();
    let isPlaying =
    $(id).get(0).currentTime > 0 &&
    !$(id).get(0).paused &&
    !$(id).get(0).ended &&
    $(id).get(0).readyState > 2;

    if (isPlaying) {
    $(id)
      .get(0)
      .pause();
    }
  };
```

How do I get the videos to ALWAYS stop playing on mouse exit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `mouseenter.trigger` and `mouseleave.trigger`. Trigger event listeners are attached directly to the html element (as opposed to on the body tag like delegates are) and can be a little more responsive depending on how big your pages age.

Additionally, you could try wrapping (some of) your event handler logic in a `TaskQueue.queueMicroTask` call inside the event callbacks. This executes your code the next `requestAnimationFrame` and ensures the element is ready to respond to your changes.

And perhaps store the element in a variable so you don't need to query the DOM more than once.

Example:

```
hideVideo = index => {
  const id = "#video" + "-" + index.toString();
  const video = $(id).get(0);
  const isPlaying = video.currentTime > 0
    && !video.paused 
    && !video.ended
    && video.readyState > 2;

  if (isPlaying) {
    // if the element is still somehow busy during mouseleave
    this.taskQueue.queueMicroTask(() => {
      video.pause();
    });
  }
}
```

Or:

```
hideVideo = index => {
  const id = "#video" + "-" + index.toString();
  const video = $(id).get(0);

  // if the state isn't always up-to-date in time
  this.taskQueue.queueMicroTask(() => {
    const isPlaying = video.currentTime > 0
      && !video.paused 
      && !video.ended
      && video.readyState > 2;

    if (isPlaying) {
      video.pause();
    }
  });
}
```

If that still doesn't work, maybe the state of the video is not what you're expecting it to be. An operation like `pause()` should be idempotent, so you could try just skipping the `isPlaying` check altogether.

Comment: As `mouseenter` doesn't bubble up you could call all your videos to pause on parent element's own `mouseenter` element.